# PHP Проверить наличие элемента в глубоком массиве без array_key_exists и ошибок

Tags: php, синтаксис

Есть многомерный массив, нужно коротко узнать есть ли элемент, задав просто путь.

К примеру `if($user['temp']['active_apply']['wait']))`

Но при этом возникают варнинги и иногда ошибки. Есть ли способ проверить все эти ключи валидно, и без такого:

```
array_key_exists ('temp', $user) && array_key_exists ('active_apply', $user['temp']) && array_key_exists ('wait', $user['temp']['active_apply'])
```

Версия 7.1

Comment: Для этого [есть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576671/php-testing-for-existence-of-a-cell-in-a-multidimensional-array) [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php), только учтите что там говорится про null значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно использование функции isset() вам поможет:

```
if( isset( $user['temp']['active_apply']['wait'] ) ) {}
```

Comment: В комментарии под вопросом есть важное замечание, без которого этот ответ будет считаться неверным